# ld: can't open output file for writing: bin/s, errno=2 for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I'm trying to compile my code on OSX El Capitan. This is my Makefile

```
TARGET   = proj_name

CC       = gcc
# compiling flags 
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -I.

LINKER   = gcc -o
# linking flags 
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONEY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

I keep getting the following error while compiling on El Capitan

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: bin/proj, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
```

I understand that its a linker issue, but if someone could help me amending the Makefile, it would really help.

Comment: What is hard to understand? Just check permissions of `bin/proj` also (I don't know how would this be in OS X) check if `bin/proj` is being executed.

Answer (score 10):

Errno 2 means (google for something like errno list):

```
#define ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
```

`bin/proj` is relative path.

Looking at the Makefile, the most likely cause seems to be, `bin` directory simply does not exist. `ld` will not try create it if it is not there. To fix, add

```
mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
```

before `$(LINKER)` line (`-p` switch allows creating a path if it does not exist, which in this case prevents error if `bin` already exists).

A side note: Another common cause with relative paths is, that working directory is not what you think it is, when `ld` is run. Adding command like `pwd` to before `$(LINKER)` command would help troubleshooting this. But looking at Makefile, this probably is not the reason here.