# Makefile confusion ' errno=2 for architecture x86_64'

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, clang

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config opencv --cflags` -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11
LIBS = `pkg-config opencv --libs`

% : src/%.cpp src/%.h
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -g -o bin/$@ $< -O3 $(LIBS)

clean:
        rm -rf bin/*
```

When I run `make skin-detect'

I get this error:

```
make skin-detect
c++ `pkg-config opencv --cflags` -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -g -o bin/skin-detect src/skin-detect.cpp -O3 `pkg-config opencv --libs`
ld: can't open output file for writing: bin/skin-detect, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [skin-detect] Error 1
```

I'm on Mac Catalina. This post:

[ld: can't open output file for writing: bin/s, errno=2 for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984058/ld-cant-open-output-file-for-writing-bin-s-errno-2-for-architecture-x86-64)

seems to address the issue, but I don't understand the recommendation. Do I need to instruct `bin/skin-detect/` to be made manually? I'm very new to compilers...

Comment: Does `bin` exist?

Comment: Where should it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't add formatting in comments: you should be able to do something like this:

```
% : src/%.cpp src/%.h
        mkdir -p bin
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -g -o bin/$@ $< -O3 $(LIBS)
```

if the problem is really that the `bin` directory doesn't exist.  However of course there could be other issues.

One thing you said in your question mentioned `bin/skin-detect/` with a trailing slash.  Was that a typo?  Or does `bin/skin-detect` already exist as a directory?  Because if it already exists as a directory then the linker can't write a file with that name.

What does `ls -l bin/skin-detect` show?  If it already exists as a directory, or even as a file that you don't have write permissions for, you should rename that directory or remove it if you don't want it, then try your build.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a rule to your makefile to create the directory.
something like:

```
BINDIR=bin
CFLAGS = `pkg-config opencv --cflags` -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11
LIBS = `pkg-config opencv --libs`

$(BINDIR):
        mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

% : src/%.cpp src/%.h $(BINDIR)
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -g -o bin/$@ $< -O3 $(LIBS)
```

Comment: You need an order-only dependency for the directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464506/412080

Comment: Yes you should never use basic prerequisites to depend on directories.  Even simpler is to just put the `mkdir` in the recipe, before you invoke the link step.

Comment: I just replaced my Makefile with your suggestion and I still get this error: `ld: can't open output file for writing: bin/skin-detect, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
`

Comment: @MadScientist how do I do this?